# RKManagedObjectRequestOperation queuing

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

Hello I am currently using the RKManagedObjectRequestOperation to make queued requests. I've set the maximum concurrent connection to 1 and enqueued the request.

My issue is the following.

If I make a request A, then make a request B. Shouldn't request B wait for request A to finish first before B starts. I would expect a FIFO type of queue but right now request A starts, then request B starts then request A seems to wait for request B to finish first which doesn't seem right. Do I need to the RKManagedObjectRequestOperation to my own managed queue? This seems to defeat the purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: Show code. The request and the mapping are separate. Explain what you need to complete before other stuff.

Comment: Yeah just read that the mapping is separate. So that might be my issue where I expect the request and mapping to occur in sequential order.

Comment: Something similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880223/restkit-0-2x-simultaneous-rkmanagedobjectrequestoperation